# How to correctly add "scalaz-core_2.10-7.0.0.jar" to scala project

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-ide

When I add **"scalaz-core_2.10-7.0.0.jar"** lib to build path my scala project following error appears:

[image]

Comment: did you do `clean and build` after adding ?

Comment: @ajduke yes I do clean and build, but didn't help

Comment: isn't it easier to make sbt project with scalaz dependency and then generate eclipse project?

Comment: If it easier, you can create new empty project and send to my email: mr.boyfox@gmail.com ?

Comment: See [giter8](https://github.com/n8han/giter8). There is a template with scalaz.

Comment: It works well for me, the only difference is using the IDE with Scala 2.10.2. What is the Scala IDE version you are using?

Comment: @mr.boyfox my question is about the IDE version. Is it 3.0.0?

Comment: I used the following `build.sbt` to bring the dependency, and the generate an Eclipse project file:
```
name := "scalaz-test"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.0"
```

Comment: @Lilian Dragos it is Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2